# Electrometer amplifier circuits - surface mount or traditional

Tags: amplifier, precision

I have looked at a number of electrometer amplifiers and they all seem to use big through hole passive components and through hole DIL packages. Is there a reason for not using surface mount?

Comment: SMD vs through-hole is also related to: what year was the device designed and made ? Maybe some of the components used were/are only available in DIP. An Electrometer amplifier is not a high-volume device, there might be no cost benefit to use SMD. These devices might use high voltages, then through-hole might be a better choice.

Comment: also, in such cases as yours, offering a link to a couple of these that you found might simply make your question "prettier".

Comment: also, any electrometer I've seen was based on FET-based amplifiers with small gate charges - and I'd assume those are available in pretty small packages, so I'm not sure what you're referring to!

Comment: @FakeMoustache The only ones I have seen are relatively old designs, so it *might* be because of that. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

The point of electrometers is usually very high impedance.  One possible reason for using large components is the larger creepage distances.

Physically large components are thru hole.  With larger size, the dimensional differences due to temperature will be greater.  Surface mount parts don't work well in that case since they are rigidly held to the board.  Thru hole mounting provides some inherent strain relief from dimensional changes.

Of course if your devices were made in the 1980s or earlier, then thru hole or even point to point were the only options.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think this still applies. All you need for an electrometer is essentially something that can amplify very small currents – and considering the (ancient) OPA128 is still sold by TI labeled as "Electrometer-grade Opamp", albeit it having an "incredibly high" 75 pA bias current, a lot of modern FET-based opamps will do.

For example: The [LMP7721](http://www.ti.com/product/lmp7721) has something like an expected 3 pA bias current within "normal" operating conditions (ie. not on fire) and comes in a relatively tiny SOIC-8 SMD package, or smaller. Since for the first stage of an electrometer, a simple unity gain voltage follower is sufficient, there's not much problem building a circuit that has little additional leakage current on the observed input.

Hence, the problem really is in the design of the measurement circuitry: How does one avoid that the lines between amplifier and observed charge don't form a capacity in the same order of magnitude as the charged object?

That might very well be solved by making sure there's no traces above e.g. a ground plane etc, making a very "wire-y" design maybe preferable. I personally presume that within the physical possibilities, there's probably harder problems to solve than eliminating trace capacitance.

Comment: This high performance electrometer amp only seems to come in SM http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4530-1.pdf

Comment: @DirkBruere you'll find that most semiconductor devices that are designed in the last 20 years are only available in SMD packages; DIP really only exists for legacy and niché applications.

Comment: (by the way, DIY/"Maker"/Ham are all niche applications – you never sell 100k+ units of a single type into these markets, so it makes no sense to design a semiconductor for these.)

Comment: I'm a professional EE looking to replace and update the design of electrometer used in a flame ionization detector currently supplied to our company on an OEM basis. I have not done high sensitivity stuff before at the fA level.

Comment: @DirkBruere to be perfectly honest, neither have I – I mostly work in a RF / Software Defined Radio context. But my starting point would really be a low-bias-current Opamp in a voltage feedback configuration on a small PCB, and see where I could take it from there by measuring noise etc. The Ham/DIY remark was not directed at you – there's just too much people out there that think TI, Qualcomm/NXP, Maxim, Intel etc exist for the sole purpose of supplying DIP IC samples to enthusiasts :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the INA116 by Texas Instruments. It's super low bias, and has an input impedance measured in millions of Gigaohms. It has built in guard band amps, and voltage follower inputs. Gain control resistor setting, and other nicities. It does cost about $20.00 per chip, but they are an amazing input amplifier. For amplifying a microphone, there's nothing better. Hum and noise rejection is amazing. Check it out.